# Gold Half-Life and the Longevity of Gold Curiosity

Tags: elements

I was curious if the half life of Gold is 186 Days, then why does it 'Last forever' ... Wouldn't the ancient Egyptian gold artifacts be decayed to lighter elements by now like platinum? I know gold was able to withstand corrosion very well, but the relatively short half-life is kinda throwing off my understanding of why it 'last forever'.

Comment: 186 days, eh? Wow, it must have decayed completely ages ago. Gold is a myth. There is no gold.

Comment: @Ivan maybe the gold is constantly replenished by the action of cosmic rays?  Like carbon-14?  Which reminds me:  Always know what isotopes you're dealing with.

Comment: @Oscar It would take quite a bit of ingenuity to explain the apparent stability of certain centuries-old golden items. But I'm sure we can come up with something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gold has only one stable isotope, $\ce{^197Au}$, which has $100\%$ natural abundance, thus considered to be one of monoisotopic elements (one of 26 chemical elements which have only a single stable isotope). As a matter of facts, it is now considered to be the heaviest monoisotopic element. For more info, read [Isotopes of gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_gold).

Aside $\ce{^197Au}$, there are 36 unstable isotopes of gold been known ranging from $\ce{^169Au}$ to $\ce{^205Au}$. All of these are radioisotopes (radioactive nuclides). The $\ce{^195Au}$ isotope is the most stable amongst unstable isopopes, with a half-life ($t_{1/2}$) of $\pu{186 d}$. The heaviest, $\ce{^205Au}$, has $t_{1/2}$ of $\pu{31 s}$ ([ref](http://periodictable.com/Isotopes/079.205/index.p.full.html)).

Comment: To rephrase so it's perfectly clear, $\ce{^195Au}$ , with a half life of 186 days, is the the most stable *of the gold isotopes which are unstable*. $\ce{^197Au}$ is even more stable than $\ce{^195Au}$, with an effectively infinite half life.

Answer (score 4):

Gold has a [number of isotopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_gold). $\ce{^{197}Au}$ is stable and is the only isotope which is. So all the gold that is mined is $\ce{^{197}Au}$.